# Is it possible to access nth element of a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a snippet of code in which the function foo returns a dictionary.

```
def foo():
    # do something here
    # get data from web
    return {
        "book": {ln : wd for ln, wd, _ in data["book"]},
        "note": {ln : wd for ln, wd, _ in data["note"]},
    }

def bar():
    data = foo()
    # how to access 0th element of data["book"]
    # data["book"][0] doesnt work
```

The question is how can I access its first element?

Comment: Unless you're using python 3.7, the language makes no guarantee of the order of the items of your dictionary. Are you sure you want a dictionary here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`list(data.items())` will give you a list version of all entries in the dictionary as tuples of the form `(key, value)` that you can iterate over or index as needed:

```
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> print(list(d.items())[0])
('a', 1)
```

So in your case, `list(data['books'].items())`

Answer (score -1):

I think this works and it's a lot simpler than the other way:

```
data['book'[0]]
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. It access a dictionaries `"b"`-value, not a numerically defined index.